# H2 delay with large data when i use where with order or like

Tags: mysql, sql, database, h2

i must use the where query because i have 2 database in same place so the cid=1 and cid=2 should be in query
i will put the analyze explain of H2 console ..

> explain analyze select name, (TIMESTAMPDIFF('YEAR', date_of_birth,
> CURDATE())) as age from campaigns_people where cid=1 order by name asc
> limit 10

the response are:

> SELECT
> "NAME",
> DATEDIFF(YEAR, "DATE_OF_BIRTH", CURRENT_DATE) AS "AGE" FROM "PUBLIC"."CAMPAIGNS_PEOPLE"
> /* PUBLIC.PERSON_CAMPAIGN: CID = CAST(1 AS BIGINT) */
> /* scanCount: 150194 */ WHERE "CID" = CAST(1 AS BIGINT) ORDER BY 1 FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY /* reads: 13036
> */

as shown the scancount all data in db which is 150194
and it is lagging (1 row, 4116 ms)

while i need only to get the 10 results ..

when am using this query everything is ok when i delete the where:

> explain analyze select name, (TIMESTAMPDIFF('YEAR', date_of_birth,
> CURDATE())) as age from campaigns_people order by name asc limit 10

the response are ok as shown:

> SELECT
> "NAME",
> DATEDIFF(YEAR, "DATE_OF_BIRTH", CURRENT_DATE) AS "AGE"
> FROM "PUBLIC"."CAMPAIGNS_PEOPLE"
> /* PUBLIC.PERSON_NAME */
> /* scanCount: 10 */
> ORDER BY 1
> FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
> /* index sorted */
> /*
> reads: 16
> */

no lag and grep exactly 10 rows.

any good answer will be appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

For H2 you need to create an additional index on `(CID, NAME)` columns **and** use `ORDER BY CID, NAME` instead of `ORDER BY NAME` to enable **both** filtration with an index and index-sorted optimization:

```sql
CREATE INDEX CAMPAIGNS_PEOPLE_CID_NAME_INDEX ON CAMPAIGNS_PEOPLE(CID, NAME);

explain select name, (TIMESTAMPDIFF('YEAR', date_of_birth, CURDATE())) as age
from campaigns_people where cid=1 order by cid, name asc limit 10;
```

```sql
SELECT
    "NAME",
    DATEDIFF(YEAR, "DATE_OF_BIRTH", CURRENT_DATE) AS "AGE"
FROM "PUBLIC"."CAMPAIGNS_PEOPLE"
    /* PUBLIC.CAMPAIGNS_PEOPLE_CID_NAME_INDEX: CID = 1 */
WHERE "CID" = 1
ORDER BY "CID", 1
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
/* index sorted */
```

Ordered queries with `FETCH` (or non-standard `LIMIT`) clause can stop their execution early only when index-sorted optimization is possible. Without it they need to read all matched rows, sort them, and truncate the result to the specified number of rows.

Comment: If i add extra column with name the index will be messy here below are what happened . explain select *, (TIMESTAMPDIFF('YEAR', date_of_birth, CURDATE())) as age from campaigns_people where cid=1 order by cid, name asc limit 10;